# Create form in back office by module Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I made a module to hook a form in product page in the back office (with hook `DisplayAdminProductExtra`). 
**How can I create a form with some inputs by module?**

I think it can  be done by {`helper` and `.tpl` file} or {`form_field` and `.twig` file}.
If anyone explains this as a walkthrough I'm sure it's gonna be a good reference for many others too.
this is the code that created by PrestaShop module generator:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Myfirstmodule extends Module
{
    protected $config_form = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'myfirstmodule';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'parsa';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        /**
         * Set $this->bootstrap to true if your module is compliant with bootstrap (PrestaShop 1.6)
         */
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('new module');
        $this->description = $this->l('first module');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure?');

        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    /**
     * Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
     * http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
     */
    public function install()
    {
        Configuration::updateValue('MYFIRSTMODULE_LIVE_MODE', false);

        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('header') &&
            $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        Configuration::deleteByName('MYFIRSTMODULE_LIVE_MODE');

        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    /**
     * Load the configuration form
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        /**
         * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
         */
        if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitMyfirstmoduleModule')) == true) {
            $this->postProcess();
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign('module_dir', $this->_path);

        $output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path . 'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');

        return $output . $this->renderForm();
    }

    /**
     * Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
     */
    protected function renderForm()
    {
        $helper = new HelperForm();

        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->table = $this->table;
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);

        $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitMyfirstmoduleModule';
        $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
            . '&configure=' . $this->name . '&tab_module=' . $this->tab . '&module_name=' . $this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

        $helper->tpl_vars = array(
            'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
            'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
            'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
        );

        return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
    }

    /**
     * Create the structure of your form.
     */
    protected function getConfigForm()
    {
        return array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'label' => $this->l('Live mode'),
                        'name' => 'MYFIRSTMODULE_LIVE_MODE',
                        'is_bool' => true,
                        'desc' => $this->l('Use this module in live mode'),
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => true,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => false,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'col' => 3,
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'prefix' => '<i class="icon icon-envelope"></i>',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Enter a valid email address'),
                        'name' => 'MYFIRSTMODULE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL',
                        'label' => $this->l('Email'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'password',
                        'name' => 'MYFIRSTMODULE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD',
                        'label' => $this->l('Password'),
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set values for the inputs.
     */
    protected function getConfigFormValues()
    {
        return array(
            'MYFIRSTMODULE_LIVE_MODE' => Configuration::get('MYFIRSTMODULE_LIVE_MODE', true),
            'MYFIRSTMODULE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL' => Configuration::get('MYFIRSTMODULE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', 'contact@prestashop.com'),
            'MYFIRSTMODULE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD' => Configuration::get('MYFIRSTMODULE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD', null),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Save form data.
     */
    protected function postProcess()
    {
        $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();

        foreach (array_keys($form_values) as $key) {
            Configuration::updateValue($key, Tools::getValue($key));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be loaded in the BO.
     */
    public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name) {
            $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/back.js');
            $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . 'views/css/back.css');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be added on the FO.
     */
    public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . '/views/js/front.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . '/views/css/front.css');
    }

    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra()
    {
        /* Place your code here. */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on Stack Overflow

using HelperForm on PrestaShop 1.7 product  page is not really working at this moment, it is recommended to use HTML markup and get all values of the form from the $_POST using `actionProductSave` hook

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can make my form by HTML, but can you please explain more about `actionproductsave`? maybe a template of this hook in the module?

Comment: It would be better to use `hookActionAdminProductsControllerSaveAfter`, hook into `actionAdminProductsControllerSaveAfter` and try to dump $_POST to see what it returns